# Trouble with static private classes in java

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

If I have a java `class SpecificDialog` and inside that class I have a `public static class Builder` used to build an object of a `SpecificDialog` then the reason why the `Builder` is inside `SpecificDialog` is because it logically belongs there as it can only be used to build  SpecifcDialogs. Is this the main reason?

But then if `Builder` is inside `SpecificDialog` then my `SpecificDialog` has access to every `private` field/member of the `Builder`. This may be undesirable because I can inadvertently modify some such private `Builder's` field from the outside `SpecificDialog`.

Is it there nothing can be done about that and, if not, shall I understand that this is not a big concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever design you might choose, you'll always be able to inadvertently do something that shouldn't be done. Making a builder a static inner class of the class it builds is a common idiom that is used precisely because the outer class can access the private fields of the builder. Consider the builder as an integral part of the outer class, just like a private field or method, and make sure the class and its builder behave as they should.

Comment: While I understand that, in general,it's useful for an outer class to access private fields of an inner class I can't fully appreciate that for a Builder pattern. By way of analogy: we know of no building that would be able to access its builder's data such as architectural plans, if it does it can gain control over its own building process not unlike in the Terminator movie which would be undesirable. Hence there was my question.

Comment: Then you should also ask yourself why we use constructors and factory methods, because have you ever seen a building that builds itself?

Comment: While it is useful to employ metaphors to visualize and understand the principles of object oriented programming, it is also misleading: It is not a physical building you are talking about, but a piece of software.  Buildings do not have behavior of their own - software objects do.

Comment: Also, by your analogy, the building is equivalent to the compiled program - the classes represent the architectural plans.

Comment: However it can and have been argued that static factories should be preffered way fo constructing objects. And also the possibility of constructors throwing exceptions seems to indicate that there's in fact no such thing as a constructor. Regarding building's behavior we can think that no such behavior can exist before a Builder has completed its work

Comment: Again, the building metaphor is misleading. It won't help you. Arguing about creation patterns is like arguing which recipe to use for cooking: It all depends on what you're trying to cook - and at least to some part, on taste. I'm not sure I understand your argument about constructors.

Comment: factory method being a static one does not belong to an object but is simply logically grouped with it

Comment: I really don't see why the fact that a constructor may throw an exception makes constructor non-existent. And static factory methods are cool, but they can't exist without constructors, since in the end, that's what they must use to create the object.

Comment: @weltraumpirat I just meant constructors are not builders. Constructors, I believe have no real world analogy at all while builders do have and therefore constructors can play no part in the argument

Comment: That's where I think you're wrong. Builders don't have any real-world analogy. They're just a software abstraction that consists in accumulating data from severral method calls in order to provide all the accumulated data in one shot to a class constructor. They help making objects immutable while still allowing several method calls to build them.

Comment: Please try to understand: There is no fully compliant real world analogy in software design. They are metaphors used to explain *certain aspects* of OO, but not ever do they match the exact thing in *every* aspect. I promise, you will find it liberating to distance yourself from this way of thinking. It imposes artificial limits on what you can achieve with your code, and ultimately prevents you from becoming a better programmer.

Answer (score 1):

The [main reason for declaring inner classes](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-03/02-qa-innerclass.html) is to structurally separate and reorganize complex code, and provide ways to deal with Java's shortcomings with callbacks (e.g. as an equivalent to closures, which will at last be available in Java 8).

Since inherently, the inner class is a structural part of the outer class, full access to all members is not only okay, but desirable - it is what actually makes this a useful tool! Without this feature, inner classes would behave exactly in the same way any class does - and therefore provide no advantage.